# Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter with asmx web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

I have this error : "**Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter** " when I call a web service method with a parameter.

I'm testing with a web service method without parameter that returns the same type of object and it works well.

Here is my web service method :

```
 [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public ResponseStatistic_3 Statistic_3(string klant)
    {
            Statistic_3[] items = Helper.Helper_Statistic_3(klant).ToArray();
            ResponseStatistic_3 response = new ResponseStatistic_3(items);


            return response;
    }
```

Here is my javascript code, I retrieve the good value in kla variable :

```
 function getStatistic3() {

var response;
var allstat3 = [];
var kla = $('#Select1').val();
var dataJSon = { klant: kla }

if (kla) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:52251/Service1.asmx/Statistic_3',
        data: dataJSon,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        success: function (msg) {
            response = msg.d;
            for (var i = 0; i < response.Items.length; i++) {
                var j = 0;
                allstat3[i] = [response.Items[i].Interventie, response.Items[i].Sum[j], response.Items[i].Sum[++j], response.Items[i].Sum[++j], response.Items[i].Sum[++j], response.Items[i].Sum[++j]];
            }
            fillDataTable(allstat3);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert("error loading statistic 3");
        }
    });
} else {
    alert("statistic 3 null");
}
}
```

I'm testing too with JSON.stringify({ klant: kla }) and I have the same error.

I looked at several forums but in vain.
What's wrong?

Comment: FYI, you are not using WCF, but rather are using ASMX. ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: I know, I began with wcf but I had a problem I could not solve for several days. With asmx I could solve this problem very quickly. Thank you to cheer ...

Comment: What happens if you just send it as string (`data: "klant='test'"`)? does it get through?

Comment: @Jayce: you should have asked your WCF question on [so]. An answer from us is much better than using legacy technologies in new development, then being stuck with them.

Comment: @SimonC yes there isn't error and what do I replace in 'test' here?

Comment: @JohnSaunders ok I'll post soon and I hope that someone will find one response.

Comment: @Jayce. Great. Take a look at @Rob Angelier's answer. Think that looks o.k. though you might need to do something more like `data: "klant='" + $('#Select1').val() + "'"`

Comment: @Joyce But I also think that `JSON.stringify({ klant: $('#Select1').val() })` should work

Answer (score 1):

Your webservice method requires a string parameter, but you send the JSON representation of a customer object. I think the build-in JavaScriptSerializer is trying to deserialize your parameter and is causing the error. I adjusted your code in the example below:

```
function getStatistic3() {

var response;
var allstat3 = [];

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:52251/Service1.asmx/Statistic_3',
        data: $('#Select1').val(),
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        success: function (msg) {
            response = msg.d;
            for (var i = 0; i < response.Items.length; i++) {
                var j = 0;
                allstat3[i] = [response.Items[i].Interventie, response.Items[i].Sum[j], response.Items[i].Sum[++j], response.Items[i].Sum[++j], response.Items[i].Sum[++j], response.Items[i].Sum[++j]];
            }
            fillDataTable(allstat3);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert("error loading statistic 3");
        }
    });
}
```

**Webservice method**

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public ResponseStatistic_3 Statistic_3(string klant)
{
        Statistic_3[] items = Helper.Helper_Statistic_3(klant).ToArray();
        ResponseStatistic_3 response = new ResponseStatistic_3(items);
        return response;
}
```

Comment: okay, that's strange. I removed the contentType header from the request since the modified request isn't sending any json to the server, can you try again?

Comment: Can you change the "type" property to "POST" and see if that helps? There are some common issues with these old asmx services. This problem also occurs with PageMethods (almost the same) they only accept POST requests.

Comment: I found grace @SimonC --> data: "klant='" + $('#Select1').val() + "'"

Answer (score 1):

You need to stringify the parameter sefore sending it to the web service using JSON.stringify() method.

```
function getStatistic3() {

var response;
var allstat3 = [];
var kla = $('#Select1').val();
**var dataJSon = JSON.stringify({ klant: kla })**

if (kla) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:52251/Service1.asmx/Statistic_3',
        data: dataJSon,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        success: function (msg) {
            response = msg.d;
            for (var i = 0; i < response.Items.length; i++) {
                var j = 0;
                allstat3[i] = [response.Items[i].Interventie, response.Items[i].Sum[j], response.Items[i].Sum[++j], response.Items[i].Sum[++j], response.Items[i].Sum[++j], response.Items[i].Sum[++j]];
            }
            fillDataTable(allstat3);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert("error loading statistic 3");
        }
    });
} else {
    alert("statistic 3 null");
}
}
```